# Earpods doesn't work on iPhone7

Tags: audio, lightning, iphone, ear-phones

There is a big problem with the EarPods that I get with my new iPhone 7.
Inside the Apple box there was also an adapter for the 3.5mm jack and it works perfectly with other type of headphones (with 3.5mm jack) on my phone. 
However the Earpods with the lightning work only on my friend's iPhone 7, not with mine. Someone could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could reach out to Apple support if you can't bring a second pair of EarPods to test that your phone has a working lightning connector. A bit of fuzz or lint could be covering a pin or there could be a rare defect. Rd to know without testing and observing the port.